# How to point https subdomain to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have Jenkins running on EC2 `myip:8080`
I have a subdomain jenkins.mydomain.com that I want to point to my jenkins running on the EC2 instance.

What is the best approach to accomplish this?
Obviously I want it to load over HTTPS so I was thinking of perhaps creating a CloudFront distribution that would point to a S3 bucket which just redirects to the EC2 instance.

In your opinion, what is the best approach to accomplish this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jenkins.mydomain.com —> nginx (SSL termination) —> EC2 Jenkins

If you wish you can also encrypt traffic from nginx to backend servers.